# How to make list type with sample element type through reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I need to define a type of object, i recieve from service. Service has different namespace, but same object, so i wrote some parser to get names of recieved types.
But i have some troubles to detect nested list types like

```
    List<List<SomeObjectType>> 
or
    List<List<Tuple<int,int,SomeObjectType>>
```

So in my recursive function i need to make a list type with sample element type. Like this:

```
public Type getType(TypeSpec TypeInfo, string NameSpace)
{
    Type foundType = ObjectsHelper.ByName(NameSpace + "." + nameOfType);
    if (foundType == null) throw new TypeNotFoundException(TypeInfo.name);
    else
    {
        if (TypeInfo.generic_params != null && TypeInfo.generic_params.Count > 0) // if has generic params, run recursive
        {
            var listOfParams = new List<Type>();
            foreach (var gp in generic_params)
            {
                listOfParams.Add(this.getType(gp, NameSpace));
            }
            // here is a heart of the matter
            HowToAddGenericParameters(foundType, listOfParams); // ????
        }
        return foundType;
    }
}
```

Is it possible? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.100).aspx) method

```
foundType.MakeGenericType(listOfParams.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly whan i needed! foundType = foundType.MakeGenericType(listOfParams.ToArray());